# How do I edit the structure (HTML) of Genesis Framework?

Tags: wordpress, frameworks, genesis

I've just begun learning to develop with Genesis Framework, and while I understand everything seems to be reliant on hooks, I can't find the actual HTML these hooks call back to that compose the structure of the pages. I feel locked in a labyrinth of PHP calls.

I've downloaded the Genesis Sandbox template to work with, so help with that specifically would be great, but even just pointers in general would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Me too. I don't code PHP but my advice would be to start simple.

This code, added in my child theme's functions.php wraps the inner divs (in this case so I could add a CSS3 effect around the content:

```
add_action( 'genesis_before_header', 'sk_add_wraps_opening_divs', 9 );
function sk_add_wraps_opening_divs() {
echo '<div class="glow-wrap">';
}
add_action( 'genesis_after_footer', 'sk_add_wraps_closing_divs' );
function sk_add_wraps_closing_divs() {
echo '</div>';
}
```

The HTML5 from Genesis seems pretty good. Maybe you need to write completely custom templates for your site though?
There is lots of good info in the Genesis community.

Hope that helps!